# How to Create an ElasticSearch 8 Installation with High Availability on Ubuntu

Tags: elasticsearch

Today I have an installation of ElasticSearch 6, but due to my lack of knowledge I only installed it on one machine and it lives with Yellow Status.
And in case of updates or upgrades, I can't make the data available.

Is there any material that teaches me step-by-step how to configure an ES server with high availability in Ubuntu, define the correct JVM usage, set users to access, ips, etc?

The only material I can find teaches just the basics, install it on a machine and that's it.